# Select all where date in Last month sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I get last month date like

```
select * from table where date in ( last month  )
```

I dont want the last 30 days 
AND how can I get last month automatically

Comment: so many bad answers here, currently no useful answers, check the link and don't use the selected answer from the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

if you mean last month from today. or previous month from a specific date then you need to do something like this

```
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, [Date]))
```

Or to get records from previous month of the year you can do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE  MONTH(Date) =  DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, [Date]))
AND YEAR(Date) =    DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, [Date]))    --<-- or pass year for which year you are checking
```

**To make your aquery SARGable** (Suggested by t-clausen.dk)

```
select * from table 
where date >=dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, current_timestamp)-1, 0) 
and date < dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, current_timestamp)-1, 0)
```

[Read here more about sargable Queries](http://msmvps.com/blogs/robfarley/archive/2010/01/22/sargable-functions-in-sql-server.aspx) when working with date/datetime datatypes.

Comment: how can I get the last month automatically

Comment: @user3190075 MONTH(GETDATE())

Comment: last month of what ??? @user3190075

Comment: @M.Ali you are getting there. But you need to include the year in the query, otherwise the result will include records from previous years.

Comment: Year should be dynamic like month: `DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, [Date]))`

Comment: This is how you should have solved it to allow use of index: select * from table 
where date >=dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, current_timestamp)-1, 0)
and date < dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, current_timestamp)-1, 0)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk very good point cheers pal :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want all items where the date is *within the last month* i.e. between today and 30/31 days ago:

```
Select *
From Table
Where Date Between DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table
where month(date)=month(getdate())-1
```

Comment: That returns 0 (zero) for this month!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
Select * from table where date between @startdate and @enddate
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM DATE_SAMPLE WHERE 
DATEPART(YEAR, SAMPLE_DATE) = '2013' AND 
DATEPART(MONTH,SAMPLE_DATE) = '01' AND 
DATEPART(DAY, SAMPLE_DATE) = '01'
```

Is it usefull for you?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use the between statement to get the specific dates:

```
Select * from table where date between '01-01-2014' and '14-01-2014'
```